# Adding column to dataframe based on implementing rule of another column

Tags: python, pandas, function

I'm assisting on a neonatal project which basically is looking at how to give medicine dosages based on a certain score. I've essentially been given a large dataframe filled with lots of different babies and scores at different dates and time points. An example of this is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'baby': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','B','B'],
   'dateandtime':  ['8/2/2009  5:00:00 PM', '7/19/2009  5:00:00 PM', '7/19/2009  1:00:00 PM', '7/17/2009  6:00:00 AM','7/17/2009  12:01:00 AM', '7/14/2009  12:01:00 AM', '7/19/2009  5:00:00 AM', '7/16/2009  9:00:00 PM','7/19/2009  9:00:00 AM', '7/14/2009  6:00:00 PM', '7/15/2009  3:04:00 PM', '7/20/2009  5:00:00 PM','7/16/2009  12:01:00 AM', '7/18/2009  1:00:00 PM', '7/16/2009  6:00:00 AM', '7/13/2009  9:00:00 PM','7/19/2009  1:00:00 AM','7/15/2009  12:04:00 AM'],
   'score':  [6, 3, 7, 5, 10, 14, 5, 4, 11, 4, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 12, 6, 6]
})
print(df)
```

The first thing I  did was to put the babies and timestamps in chronological order (this is important) using:

```
df = df.groupby(['baby', 'dateandtime'])
```

So now what I'm trying to figure out how to do is create a column to add onto my dataframe so that at each time point, I have either a -1 (decrease dosage), 0 (keep dosage the same), or +1 (increase dosage) depending upon the "score" based on a rule developed by the team. The rule I was given is as follows: It is +1 if either the sum of 3 consecutive scores ≥ 24 or most recent one or two scores is ≥ 12. It is -1 if the average score in the past 24 hours is < 8 after the scores stays below 8 for at least 48 hours. It is 0 otherwise.

So my issue is: **I don't know really how to code this rule, especially since I'm not sure how to tell python "look at the last 48 hours"**. I think if I knew how to create a function to do this rule, I can screw around with the command `df.apply(rule).reset_index(`) and then merge it with my original `groupby` df to get the final result. Any ideas for how to convert this rule into code? I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2):

For the second part of the rule that

> -1 if the average score in the past 24 hours is < 8 after the scores stays below 8 >for at least 48 hours.

I was wondering if it means:

1. the average score in the past 24 hours is < 8
2. the maximum score of the 48 hours prior to that 24 hour-period is < 8 (that is, the maximum during the past hour 24-74 is < 8)

It's possible that the 48-hour period with scores less than 8 is the first hurdle, and then the subsequent 24-hour period with its average score less than 8 serves as the second hurdle for reducing dosage.

Importantly, it is ambiguous whether the first hurdle is cleared if such a 48-hour period data is not available.

Below is the steps to generate the maximum score between the past 24th hour and the past 72nd hour for each observation. (my apologies for a bit dirty code here)

```py
df.dateandtime = pd.to_datetime(df['dateandtime']) # change column type for ease of indexing
df = df.sort_values(by=['baby','dateandtime'])
df= df.reset_index(drop=True)


def filter_df_for_datetime_between_timedeltas(df, varname, base_datetime, time_gr= -72, time_le= -24, unit='h'):
    df['hour_diff'] = df[varname] - base_datetime
    return df[ (pd.Timedelta(time_gr, unit=unit) < df.hour_diff) & 
                (df.hour_diff < pd.Timedelta(time_le, unit=unit))]
    
    
df_24h_to_72h_max = pd.DataFrame() 

for baby in list(df.baby.unique()):
    df_baby = df[df.baby==baby]
    for row in df_baby.iterrows():
        base_datetime = row[1]['dateandtime']
        df_row_24h_to_72h = filter_df_for_datetime_between_timedeltas(df_baby, 'dateandtime', base_datetime)
        # print( df_row_24h_to_72h)
        if len(df_row_24h_to_72h):
            data_row = df_row_24h_to_72h[df_row_24h_to_72h.score==df_row_24h_to_72h.score.max()][::-1].iloc[0]
            # print(data_row)
            row_stat = dict(**row[1][:2],
                            max_24h_to_72h = data_row.score.max(),
                            max_24h_to_72h_time = data_row.dateandtime,
                            hour_diff = -data_row.hour_diff )
            df_24h_to_72h_max = df_24h_to_72h_max.append(pd.DataFrame([row_stat]), ignore_index=True)
        
        
df_24h_to_72h_max
```

and merge this data with the original dataset;

```py
df2 = df.set_index(['baby', 'dateandtime']).join(df_24h_to_72h_max.set_index(['baby', 'dateandtime']))

df2 = df2.reset_index().set_index('dateandtime')
    
#Calculate conditions
df2['sum_3_scores'] = df2.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling(3).sum().reset_index(0,drop=True)
df2['max_2_scores'] = df2.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling(2).max().reset_index(0,drop=True)
df2['mean_24hr_score'] = df2.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling('24h').mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)

#scoring logic
def score(data):
    if data['sum_3_scores'] >= 24 or data['max_2_scores'] >= 12:
        return 1
    if data['mean_24hr_score'] < 8 and data['max_24h_to_72h'] < 8: 
        return -1
    return 0

df2['rule'] = df2.apply(score, axis = 1)
df2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! You're absolutely right that the description was ambiguous, which I had realized later last evening, so we've contacted the co-authors to figure out what they actually meant

Answer (score 1):

How about trying something like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'baby': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','B','B'],
   'dateandtime':  ['8/2/2009  5:00:00 PM', '7/19/2009  5:00:00 PM', '7/19/2009  1:00:00 PM', '7/17/2009  6:00:00 AM','7/17/2009  12:01:00 AM', '7/14/2009  12:01:00 AM', '7/19/2009  5:00:00 AM', '7/16/2009  9:00:00 PM','7/19/2009  9:00:00 AM', '7/14/2009  6:00:00 PM', '7/15/2009  3:04:00 PM', '7/20/2009  5:00:00 PM','7/16/2009  12:01:00 AM', '7/18/2009  1:00:00 PM', '7/16/2009  6:00:00 AM', '7/13/2009  9:00:00 PM','7/19/2009  1:00:00 AM','7/15/2009  12:04:00 AM'],
   'score':  [6, 3, 7, 5, 10, 14, 5, 4, 11, 4, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 12, 6, 6]
})

df.dateandtime = pd.to_datetime(df['dateandtime']) # change column type for ease of indexing
df.sort_values(by=['baby', 'dateandtime'], inplace = True)

df['2_score_sum'] = df['score'].rolling(2, min_periods=2).sum()
df['3_score_sum'] = df['score'].rolling(3, min_periods=3).sum()
df['3_score_mean'] = df['score'].rolling(3, min_periods=3).mean()


df
```

it's the rolling that does the trick. More info here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

from here you can just make a simple function that checks the appropriate column and returns a value for each row.

Comment: If your index is a datetime, you can also pass a time period to rolling like '24h' to create a rolling sum by 24 hour period.

Answer (score 1):

Please double check the math and the logic, but I think this is the path.  You definitely need to group by baby or there will be some overlap in the numbers from one baby to the next.

```
df.dateandtime = pd.to_datetime(df['dateandtime']) # change column type for ease of indexing
df = df.set_index('dateandtime')
df.sort_index(inplace = True)

#Calculate conditions
df['sum_3_scores'] = df.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling(3).sum().reset_index(0,drop=True)
df['max_2_scores'] = df.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling(2).max().reset_index(0,drop=True)
df['max_48hr_score'] = df.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling('48h').mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)

#you don't nead to calculate the 24hr mean because the 48hr max is 8 the 24hr mean will also be < 8 
#df['mean_24hr_score'] = df.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling('24h').mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)

#scoring logic
def score(data):
    if data['sum_3_scores'] >= 24 or data['max_2_scores'] >= 12:
        return 1
    if data['max_48hr_score'] < 8: #if the score has been below 8 for 48 hours the average of the past 24 hours will be < 8
        return -1
    return 0

df['rule'] = df.apply(score, axis = 1)

#just for a nicely ordered output
df.reset_index().set_index(['baby','dateandtime']).sort_index()
```

yields:

```
                          score  sum_3_scores  max_2_scores  max_48hr_score  rule
baby dateandtime                                                                 
A    2009-07-14 00:01:00     14           NaN           NaN       14.000000     0
     2009-07-16 21:00:00      4           NaN          14.0        4.000000     1
     2009-07-17 00:01:00     10          28.0          10.0        7.000000     1
     2009-07-17 06:00:00      5          19.0          10.0        6.333333    -1
     2009-07-19 05:00:00      5          20.0           5.0        5.000000    -1
     2009-07-19 09:00:00     11          21.0          11.0        8.000000     0
     2009-07-19 13:00:00      7          23.0          11.0        7.666667    -1
     2009-07-19 17:00:00      3          21.0           7.0        6.500000    -1
     2009-08-02 17:00:00      6          16.0           6.0        6.000000    -1
B    2009-07-13 21:00:00     12           NaN           NaN       12.000000     0
     2009-07-14 18:00:00      4           NaN          12.0        8.000000     1
     2009-07-15 00:04:00      6          22.0           6.0        7.333333    -1
     2009-07-15 15:04:00      4          14.0           6.0        6.500000    -1
     2009-07-16 00:01:00      7          17.0           7.0        5.250000    -1
     2009-07-16 06:00:00      6          17.0           7.0        5.400000    -1
     2009-07-18 13:00:00      4          17.0           6.0        4.000000    -1
     2009-07-19 01:00:00      6          16.0           6.0        5.000000    -1
     2009-07-20 17:00:00      6          16.0           6.0        6.000000    -1
```

Comment: Hi there! So the output looks fantastic and works perfectly. I tried applying this code to my full dataset and the line under "#Calculate conditions" is giving me this problem: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. I'm not really sure what's going on since it works fine for this test dataset and it's essentially the same layout as my large one

Comment: So just as an update, I discovered my dataset has a bunch of duplicated rows which I've been able to remove using df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]. I've now rerun the code and receive the error "ValueError: window must be an integer" for the "48h" code, and this I'm unsure how to bypass

Comment: Ignore me, I have fixed it!! Turns out I'm an idiot and had a line of code greyed out with "#" and had mistyped the line "df['rule'] = df.apply(score, axis = 1)." It's way too early for this lol

Comment: Great!  I'm glad you fixed it.

Comment: Thank you! Also, I was able to get clarification about the 48 hour rule for decreasing dosages which I'm struggling a bit with the coding of. So the rule is to decrease dosages if there's at least 48 hours without needing to increase dose, the sum of the 3 most recent scores is <18, AND no single score is >8. It's pretty straight forward to look at the 48hr window and check that no single score is >8, but I'm a bit lost on how to look at the sum of the "3 most recent scores" in the 48 hour window since the .sum() would add up the entire 48 hour window

Comment: Try this:
df['sum_3_scores_48hours'] = df.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling('48h', max_periods=3).apply(lambda x: sum(x[-3:])).reset_index(0,drop=True)

Comment: I think that's actually working :). I have one last question for you and then I promise I'll stop bothering you haha (and this is probably an easy question). Your baby and dateandtime columns are nicely organized. Mine comes out like this: https://ibb.co/smSNXKf (where the A's and B's are all mixed up but it's organized by time for everything). I'm not 100% sure why this is, but is there an easy fix to organize it by baby and dateandtime like your output? Normally I'd think to do groupby but it doesn't let me print

Comment: I think I managed to get it to work! Used df.sort_values(by=['baby', 'dateandtime'],inplace=True) which seems to have fixed it

Comment: That will work, but if you want to display it as I have it with only A showing only once at the top of the baby column you can use a multiindex.  This line does that = df.reset_index().set_index(['baby','dateandtime']).sort_index() In this case it returns a copy of the df with the index so you would have to assign it to df if you want the df to have that index structure.  df = df.reset_index().set_index(['baby','dateandtime']).sort_index()

Comment: Ok I lied I have another question (sorry!). So the rule for decreasing doses requires "there's at least 48 hours without needing to increase dose". In the above example, we have -1 at "2009-07-17 06:00:00" and +1 at "2009-07-17 00:01:00" -- thus we have a -1 when we shouldn't. I'm trying to fix this but I'm truly at a loss on how to modify the score function to make sure there's no increased dosage in that 48hr window

Comment: what about df['max_48hr_rule'] = df.groupby('baby']['score'].rolling('48h').max().reset_index(0,drop=True)
Then test to see if max_48hr_rule is < 1in the scoring function.  (I didn't try it but I think it should work)